ECS not deleting old docker container when pushed to EC2
I am having an issue in my automated workflow. Current what's working: When I push a code change to main on my github repo, it pushed the Docker image to an ECR with a unique tag name, from there the ECS pulls the new docker image and creates a new task definition and revision. The old ECS service I have scales down and a new one scales up. That image then properly gets sent to the EC2. I am running a web application using vite and NPM, and the issue I am running into is that the old docker container never gets deleted when the new one pops up. Within my ECS, I have set the minimum and maximum healthy percentages to 0% and 100% to guarantee that old services get fully scaled down before new ones start.
Thus, I have to manually SSH into my EC2 instance and run this command
docker stop CONTAINER_ID
docker rm c184c8ffdf91

Then I have to manually run the new container to get my web application to show up docker
run -d -p 4173:4173 ***.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/aguacero/frontend:IMAGE_TAG
That is the only way I can get my web app to update with the new code from main, but I want this to be fully automated, which seems like it's at the 99% mark of working.
My github workflow file

name: Deploy to AWS ECR

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main 

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ***
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-2

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v2

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      id: build-and-push
      run: |
        TIMESTAMP=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
        COMMIT_SHA=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
        IMAGE_TAG=${TIMESTAMP}-${COMMIT_SHA}
        docker build -t aguacero/frontend:${IMAGE_TAG} .
        docker tag aguacero/frontend:${IMAGE_TAG}***.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/aguacero/frontend:${IMAGE_TAG}
        docker push ***.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/aguacero/frontend:${IMAGE_TAG}
        echo "IMAGE_TAG=${IMAGE_TAG}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: Retrieve latest task definition
      id: get-task-def
      run: |
        TASK_DEFINITION=$(aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition aguacero-frontend)
        echo "$TASK_DEFINITION" > task-def.json

    - name: Update task definition
      id: update-task-def
      run: |
        NEW_IMAGE="***.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/aguacero/frontend:${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }}"
        UPDATED_TASK_DEFINITION=$(jq --arg IMAGE "$NEW_IMAGE" \
          '{ 
            family: .taskDefinition.family,
            containerDefinitions: (.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions | map(if .name == "aguacero-frontend" then .image = $IMAGE else . end)),
            taskRoleArn: .taskDefinition.taskRoleArn,
            executionRoleArn: .taskDefinition.executionRoleArn,
            networkMode: .taskDefinition.networkMode,
            cpu: .taskDefinition.cpu,
            memory: .taskDefinition.memory,
            requiresCompatibilities: .taskDefinition.requiresCompatibilities,
            volumes: .taskDefinition.volumes
          }' task-def.json)
        echo "$UPDATED_TASK_DEFINITION" > updated-task-def.json

    - name: Log updated task definition
      run: |
        echo "Updated Task Definition:"
        cat updated-task-def.json

    - name: Register new task definition
      id: register-task-def
      run: |
        NEW_TASK_DEFINITION=$(aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://updated-task-def.json)
        NEW_TASK_DEFINITION_ARN=$(echo $NEW_TASK_DEFINITION | jq -r '.taskDefinition.taskDefinitionArn')
        echo "NEW_TASK_DEFINITION_ARN=${NEW_TASK_DEFINITION_ARN}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: Update ECS service
      run: |
        aws ecs update-service --cluster frontend --service aguacero-frontend --task-definition ${{ env.NEW_TASK_DEFINITION_ARN }} --force-new-deployment --region us-east-2

My DOCKERFILE
FROM node:18.16.0-slim

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app/aguacero

RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 4173

CMD [ "npm", "run", "serve" ]

My task definition for my latest push to main
{
    "family": "aguacero-frontend",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "aguacero-frontend",
            "image": "***.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/aguacero/frontend:20241003154856-60bb1fd",
            "cpu": 1024,
            "memory": 512,
            "memoryReservation": 512,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "aguacero-frontend-4173-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 4173,
                    "hostPort": 4173,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "VITE_HOST_URL",
                    "value": "http://0.0.0.0:8081"
                },
                {
                "name": "ECS_IMAGE_CLEANUP_INTERVAL",
                "value": "3600"
                },
                {
                "name": "ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIORL",
                "value": "true"
                }
            ],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/aguacero-frontend",
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            },
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::***:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::***:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "cpu": "1024",
    "memory": "512"
}

Here is what it looks like when I run docker ps the new container is there, but the old one is there and running on port 4173. Notice the push that was up 2 hours has a different tag than the one up 1 hour
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                                       NAMES
9ed96fe29eb5   ***.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/aguacero/frontend:20241003154856-60bb1fd   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   Up 1 hour    Up 1 hour                                                    ecs-aguacero-frontend-33-aguacero-frontend-8ae98bdfc1dbe985c501
b78be6681093   amazon/amazon-ecs-pause:0.1.0                                                           "/pause"                 Up 1 hour   Up 1 hour                                                  ecs-aguacero-frontend-33-internalecspause-9e8dbcc4bebec0b87500
1a70ab03320c   ***.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/aguacero/frontend:20241003153758-add572a   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   Up 2 hours   Up 2 hours        0.0.0.0:4173->4173/tcp, :::4173->4173/tcp   sad_shannon
3e697581a7a1   amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest                                                          "/agent"                 19 hours ago        Up 19 hours (healthy)                                               ecs-agent


"Notice the push that was up 2 hours has a different tag than the one up 3 minutes." 3 minutes may not be long enough to wait for it to shut down the old task. Depending on your service configuration and health check settings, it may wait for the new task to be healthy a while before deleting the old task. Have you waited some time, like 10 minutes or so, to verify it isn't terminating the old task?

@MarkB no matter how long I wait it doesn't update, we are well past the 10 minute mark now, over an hour, and I still haven't seen the changes get reflected, or the new container run, or the old container stop, I updated the question to reflect that.

I thought you were saying the new container starts, but the old container isn't removed. Are you saying you never see it deploy the new container?

Can you verify in the AWS web UI that the task definition is updated with a new image ID/tag?

@MarkB Yes I can see in the latest task definition that it is using the correct image tag when I push to main it updates to a new definition with the correct tag. When I run the command 'docker ps' I see the docker contaier with the new image tag, but it has no port mappings or anything, and I also see the older docker container from many previous pushes still running. The only way to get it to stop is by doing it manually on the command line.

Just to confirm, you haven't configured ECS to use AWS CodeDeploy to manage deployments? Also, if you go into the ECS web UI, and view the service, does it indicate it is trying to deploy a new version at all? If that last command in your GitHub workflow is actually running without any sort of error, then the ECS service should definitely be trying to deploy a new task.

@MarkB I am not using CodeDeploy at all. However, after I make a push to github, I see the old service scaling down, and the new service scaling up. It 100% is running the new service with the new image_tag and task definition revision number. I currently have a container running the frontend using that 'docker run -d -p 4173:4173...' command. When the new container gets pushed up, the old one does delete if I don't first run the command I just referenced. If I run that command the container never deletes.

So it actually works fine, exactly as intended, if you do not run any additional docker containers manually? Honestly at this point I can't keep track of what you say is happening, but your last comment makes it sound like ECS is working as intended as long as you don't login to the EC2 server and manually mess around with the docker containers on there.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The issue was:

You were manually logging into EC2 and running the task again yourself, in order to expose the task's port on the EC2 instance. This was circumventing ECS container management which then caused issues with later task deployments.
You wanted to access the ECS task via the EC2 instance's public IP address, but you could not.

The solution was to switch from network mode awsvpc which assigns a separate IP address to the ECS task, to network mode host which uses the EC2 instance's network for the ECS task. After which you can access the task via the EC2 instance's public IP address, and you can now let ECS do its job of deployment and managing your containers.
